# How to get HTML code of web-page after a query using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am very new to Selenium but I don't find any answer to this question. I have written some code that runs a search on [this](https://ondpanon.riziv.fgov.be/SilverPages/nl) site by entering the RIZIV-NR and clicking the search button. The question I have is how I can get the HTML code of the site AFTER running this search. The result of the following code is I think only the original HTML but does not have the info I want.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://ondpanon.riziv.fgov.be/SilverPages/nl")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("NihdiNumber")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("51680610")
time.sleep(4)
button = driver.find_element_by_id("SearchButton").click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(element)
```

ps. this is my first ever question here so if you need more info please tell me.

Comment: What do you need the HTML code for? Does using Chrome's developer tools not give you what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you enter the input for ***RIZIV-NR*** field and initiate the search you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) for the ***SearchResults*** and then you can extract the *`page_source`* using the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ondpanon.riziv.fgov.be/SilverPages/nl")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='NihdiNumber']"))).send_keys("51680610")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='SearchButton']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='SearchResults']")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html style="" class=" js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers no-applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths"><head><style>.gm-style-moc{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.45);pointer-events:none;text-align:center;transition:opacity ease-in-out}.gm-style-mot{color:white;font-family:Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:22px;margin:0;position:relative;top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%);-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);-ms-transform:translateY(-50%)}
  </style><style>.gm-style img{max-width: none;}.gm-style {font: 400 11px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;}</style>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>RIZIV - Zoeken</title>
      <link href="/SilverPages/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-136603939-1"></script>
      <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', 'UA-136603939-1');
      </script>

      <link href="/SilverPages/Content/css?v=nqXsXhEhXvUqGI-XBjZzVdwpXkCtCzpmQq7x-XyULgQ1" rel="stylesheet">

      <link href="/SilverPages/Content/themes/base/css?v=iUtWiGhtM4VCb8LHz23eU27gxBsVt9jn05Q7RZSvLNU1" rel="stylesheet">


      <script src="/SilverPages/bundles/modernizr?v=dUz_C7QKTmbjqpHGnN4fhYIhS-YQnnG5Pqseul2b8PQ1"></script>

      <script src="/SilverPages/bundles/jquery?v=lAWanvxuK91VI6uSCdWzhvtofm0aK0rptSpK6X6X2d01"></script>

      <script src="/SilverPages/bundles/jqueryui?v=G3zUI26k8shDvs3PSo5GPkxFSWclClRdLVUnA01ZKc01"></script>

      <script src="/SilverPages/bundles/jqueryval?v=8cA8qijPw0YgarjqUNELeEbhw5EBPkFVGxUnJZt_13U1"></script>

      <script src="/SilverPages/bundles/jqueryplugins?v=EbWBzsX99QRVUrnPAvNPrmTjH0epEBjaSUbHCy7rZpU1"></script>


      <script src="/SilverPages/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/48/10/intl/nl_ALL/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/48/10/intl/nl_ALL/util.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/48/10/intl/nl_ALL/map.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/48/10/intl/nl_ALL/onion.js"></script></head>
  <body>
          <div id="wrap">
                  <div id="banner">
                          <div class="container" id="logo">
                                  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                                          <div class="col-md-2">
                                                  <ul id="languages">


  <li><a href="/SilverPages/nl/App/SetCulture?culture=nl-BE" class="active">nl</a></li>
  <li><a href="/SilverPages/nl/App/SetCulture?culture=fr-BE" class="">fr</a></li>
                                                  </ul>

                                                  <form method="post" action="/SilverPages/nl/App/SetCulture" id="languageForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                                                          <input id="language" name="language" type="hidden" value="">
                                                          <input id="returnUrl" name="returnUrl" type="hidden" value="/SilverPages/nl">
                                                  </form>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-md-10 text-right hidden-xs small">
                                                  <img src="/SilverPages/Content/images/blgm_beLogo.gif" style="float: right;">
                                                  <div class="beborder">
                                                          Terug naar de website van het Riziv: <a href="http://www.riziv.be/">riziv.be</a> -
                              Andere informatie en overheidsdiensten: <a href="http://www.belgium.be/nl">belgie.be</a>
                                                  </div>
                                          </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">

                                                  <img src="/SilverPages/Content/images/riziv-logo-nl.png">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-md-8 visible-md visible-lg">
                                                  <h4 style="color: #009cbb;">Rijksinstituut voor ziekte- en invaliditeitsverzekering</h4>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 text-right hidden">

                                          </div>
                                  </div>
                          </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
                          <div class="container">
                                  <div class="navbar-header">
                                          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                          </button>
                                          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/SilverPages/nl">Een zorgverlener zoeken</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="NavMain">
                                                  <li id="NavHomeIndex" class="active"><a href="/SilverPages/nl">Zoeken</a></li>
                                                  <li id="NavHomeContact"><a href="/SilverPages/nl/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>


                                          </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                          </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container">
                          <div class="alert alert-info" id="CookieNotification">
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                                  <strong>Cookies</strong>
                                  <p>Onze webtoepassing maakt gebruik van cookies, onder andere om de website te analyseren en zich aan te passen aan de bezoekerservaring. Door gebruik te maken van deze website geeft u toestemming voor het gebruik van cookies. Klik op «Bevestigen» om uw toestemming te registreren en deze boodschap niet meer te zien.</p>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right;" id="CookieButton">Bevestigen</button>
                          </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container">




  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="well more-info">
              <p>
                  Zoekt u een zorgverlener en wilt u weten of hij/zij geconventioneerd is? Dan kan u via deze webtoepassing een opzoeking doen. Indien de zorgverlener geconventioneerd is, bent u zeker dat u de officiële tarieven betaalt, zonder supplementen (behalve in situaties waarbij deze supplementen reglementair zijn toegelaten).<br>
              </p>
              <div class="hidden more-info-content">
                  <table class="table-condensed">
                      <tbody><tr>
                          <td colspan="2">
                              Als de zorgverlener via
                              <a href="http://www.riziv.be/">MyRiziv</a>
                              een werkadres geregistreerd heeft, is dit adres zichtbaar in de zoekresultaten. U heeft in dat geval ook de mogelijkheid dit adres te bekijken op een kaart.
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <img src="/SilverPages/Content/images/starOfLife_yes_sm.png">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              Geconventioneerd: past de officiële tarieven toe (behalve in situaties waarbij supplementen reglementair zijn toegelaten).
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <img src="/SilverPages/Content/images/starOfLife_partial_sm.png">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              Gedeeltelijk geconventioneerd: past de officiële tarieven gedeeltelijk toe, d.w.z. past de officiële tarieven toe op bepaalde tijdstippen (bepaalde dagen of bepaalde uren op een dag) of op bepaalde plaatsen (bv. privé-praktijk of ziekenhuispraktijk), behalve in situaties waarbij supplementen reglementair zijn toegelaten.
  Alleen de artsen en tandartsen kunnen gedeeltelijk geconventioneerd zijn.
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <img src="/SilverPages/Content/images/starOfLife_no_sm.png">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              Niet geconventioneerd: is vrij om de honoraria te bepalen.
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <img src="/SilverPages/Content/images/starOfLife_unknown_sm.png">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              Conventioneringsstatuut nog niet gekend.
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>&nbsp;_</td>
                          <td>Geen overeenkomst/akkoord voor dit beroep (dit is altijd het geval voor diëtisten, ergotherapeuten, orthoptisten en podologen).</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody></table>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info more-info-toglle" style="float: right;" data-text-expanded="Minder informatie" data-text-collapsed="Meer informatie">Meer informatie</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
          <form id="SearchForm" novalidate="novalidate">
              <div class="row">
                      <input class="form-control" id="NorthEastLat" name="NorthEastLat" type="hidden">

                      <input class="form-control" id="NorthEastLng" name="NorthEastLng" type="hidden">

                      <input class="form-control" id="SouthWestLat" name="SouthWestLat" type="hidden">

                      <input class="form-control" id="SouthWestLng" name="SouthWestLng" type="hidden">

              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                          <label for="LastName">Naam</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Naam" type="text">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                          <label for="FirstName">Voornaam</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="Voornaam" type="text">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                          <label for="Profession">Wat</label>
   <small class="text-muted">(Beroep)</small>
                      <select class="form-control" id="Profession" name="Profession" onchange="GetSpecialities(this.value)">
                          <option selected="selected" value="">Alle beroepen</option>
                              <option value="20">Apotheker</option>
                              <option value="68">Apotheker-bioloog</option>
                              <option value="10">Arts</option>
                              <option value="67">Audicien</option>
                              <option value="62">Bandagist</option>
                              <option value="56">Diëtist</option>
                              <option value="65">Ergotherapeut</option>
                              <option value="50">Kinesitherapeut</option>
                              <option value="98">Klinisch orthopedagoog</option>
                              <option value="78">Klinisch psycholoog</option>
                              <option value="63">Leverancier implantaten</option>
                              <option value="58">Logopedist</option>
                              <option value="66">Opticien</option>
                              <option value="61">Orthopedist</option>
                              <option value="59">Orthoptist</option>
                              <option value="57">Podoloog</option>
                              <option value="30">Tandarts</option>
                              <option value="41">Verpleegkundige</option>
                              <option value="40">Vroedvrouw</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div id="speciality-section" class="on-form-reset-clear"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                          <label for="ConventionStatus">Conventioneringsstatus</label>

                      <select class="form-control" id="ConventionStatus" name="ConventionStatus">
                          <option selected="selected" value="">Alle statussen</option>
                              <option value="A">Geconventioneerd</option>
                              <option value="P">Gedeeltelijk geconventioneerd</option>
                              <option value="R">Niet geconventioneerd</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                          <label for="Where">Waar</label>
   <small class="text-muted">(Postcode, gemeente of stad)</small>    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span><input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="Where" name="Where" placeholder="Postcode, gemeente of stad" type="text" autocomplete="off">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                          <label for="NihdiNumber">RIZIV-nr</label>
   <small class="text-muted">(8 eerste cijfers of minder)</small>    <input class="form-control valid" id="NihdiNumber" name="NihdiNumber" placeholder="RIZIV-nr" type="text">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 form-group" id="qualDiv">
                          <label for="Qualification">Kwalificatie</label>
   <small class="text-muted">(Bevoegdheidscode, 3 cijfers)</small>    <input class="form-control" id="Qualification" name="Qualification" placeholder="Bevoegdheidscode, 3 cijfers" type="text">

                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                      <!-- No map -->
                      <div id="NoResults" style="display: none">
                          <!-- zero results -->
                          <small><i>Geen resultaten gevonden, gelieve uw zoekopdracht te verfijnen.</i> </small>
                      </div>
                      <div id="ToMuchResults" style="display: none">
                          <!-- to many results -->
                          <small><i>Er zijn te veel resultaten om op een kaart te tonen. Gelieve uw zoekopdracht te verfijnen.</i> </small>
                      </div>
                      <div id="NotConformCriteria" style="display: none">
                          <!-- show text -->
                          <small><i>Om de zoekresultaten op een kaart te kunnen weergeven, moet u minstens zoeken op beroep, naam of RIZIV-nummer.</i> </small>
                      </div>
                      <button id="ShowAllOnMapButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info more-info" style="display: none" onclick="showMap()">
                          Toon alle resultaten op de kaart
                      </button>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

                  </div>

                      <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                          <span id="results-count" class="on-form-reset-clear"><img src="/SilverPages/Content/images/spinner.gif"></span>
                          <button id="ResetButton" type="reset" class="btn btn-info form-reset-ajax" onclick="mapReset(true);">
                              Wissen
                          </button>

                          <button id="SearchButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info form-submit-ajax init-search" onclick="mapReset(true);" data-action="/SilverPages/nl/Home/SearchByForm?PageOffset=0&amp;PageSize=200" data-target="#SearchResults">
                              Zoeken
                          </button>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12" id="TitleMapWorkAddress2" style="display: none">
                      <br>
                      <div class="well">
                          <p>
                              Op deze kaart vindt u de zorgverleners terug die beantwoorden aan uw zoekcriteria en die bij het RIZIV een werkadres hebben geregistreerd. U kan via de kaart het gebied waar u een zorgverlener zoekt uitbreiden, verkleinen of verplaatsen (met het handje). Klik nadat u de kaart verplaatst heeft terug op 'dit gebied doorzoeken'.<br>
                          </p>
                          <div id="titleMapWorkAddressInfoContent" style="display: none">
                              <p>Aan de hand van de verschillende icoontjes kan u op de kaart in één oogopslag zien waar een zorgverlener werkt en wat zijn conventioneringsstatus is. Als u klikt op een icoontje, ziet u de basisgegevens van de zorgverlener.</p>
  <p>Wilt u het gebied waar u een zorgverlener zoekt uitbreiden of kleiner maken? Gebruik dan de zoomfunctie en klik vervolgens op “Dit gebied doorzoeken” om uw zoekresultaten te vernieuwen. U kan ook de kaart verslepen en daarna op dezelfde manier uw zoekresultaten aanpassen.</p>
  <p>De getoonde adressen zijn de werkadressen die zorgverleners via <a href=" http://www.myriziv.be" target="_blank">MyRiziv</a> geregistreerd hebben. Zorgverleners zonder werkadres vindt u wel in de resultatenlijst, maar niet op de kaart. Als een zorgverlener zijn werkadres wijzigt, is dit hier vanaf de volgende dag hier zichtbaar.</p>
                          </div>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info more-info" style="float: right;" id="titleWorkAdddresInfo">Meer informatie</button>
                      </div>
                      <br>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12" id="TitleMapNoWorkAddress" style="display: none">
                      <p>
                          <br>
                          <strong>Geen enkele zorgverlener in de zoekresultaten heeft bij het RIZIV een werkadres geregistreerd. We kunnen de resultaten dan ook niet via de kaart weergeven. Kies een nieuw zoekgebied door in de kaart de zoomfunctie te gebruiken of de kaart te verslepen en klik vervolgens op “Dit gebied doorzoeken” om uw zoekresultaten te vernieuwen. </strong>
                          <br>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row" id="mapcontainer" style="display: none">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                              <div class="row" align="center">
                                  <span id="results-count-map" class="on-form-reset-clear"></span>
                                  <button id="SearchButtonMap" type="button" class="btn btn-info form-submit-ajax init-search-map" onclick="GetCoordinates()" data-action="/SilverPages/nl/Home/SearchByMap?PageOffset=0&amp;PageSize=200" data-target="#SearchResults">
                                      Dit gebied doorzoeken
                                  </button>

                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body" id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden;"><div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"><div style="overflow: hidden;"></div><div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px;"><div tabindex="0" aria-label="Kaart" aria-roledescription="kaart" role="region" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; cursor: url(&quot;https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur&quot;), default; touch-action: pan-x pan-y;"><div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 101; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 102; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 103; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"></div></div><div style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: pan-x pan-y;"><div style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 104; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 105; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"><span id="4CFF71D5-5B09-48A7-A1A8-049A03DBF164" style="display: none;">Druk op de pijltoetsen om te navigeren.</span></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 107; width: 100%;"></div></div></div><div class="gm-style-moc" style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 0;"><p class="gm-style-mot"></p></div></div><iframe aria-hidden="true" frameborder="0" tabindex="-1" style="z-index: -1; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: none;"></iframe><div style="pointer-events: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; z-index: 1000002; opacity: 0; border: 2px solid rgb(26, 115, 232);"></div></div></div></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  .   
  .
  <script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBaXLvd35FOBehSmQkdZDHs7QZb-N5plHM&amp;callback=initMap&amp;language=nl&amp;region=BE&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>


  <div id="SearchResults" class="on-form-reset-clear">
  </div>

                  </div>

          </div>

          <div class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #c6e5ec;">
                  <div class="container">
                          <br>
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                                  <p style="font-size: 90%">©RIZIV, alle rechten voorbehouden</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <p style="color: #2d3235; font-size: 85%">
                                          Dev 3.4.769.1 (04-06-21)
                                          <a style="color: #808080; font-size: 85%">
                                                   - 1.53.2085.1 (21/04/21)
                                          </a>
                          </p></div>
                          <div class="col-md-1">
                                  <p>
                                          <a style="font-size: 90%; color: #2d3235" href="/SilverPages/nl/Home/Liability">Disclaimer</a>
                                  </p>
                          </div>
                  </div>
          </div>


          <a id="back-top" class="hidden-print" href="#top" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
          </a>


      <script src="/SilverPages/Scripts/Nihdi-SilverPages.js"></script>



  <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></ul><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -2px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; width: 1px;"><span style="position: absolute; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">BESbswy</span></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -2px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; width: 1px;"><span style="position: absolute; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">BESbswy</span></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -2px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; width: 1px;"><span style="position: absolute; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">BESbswy</span></div></body></html>
  ```

Comment: I see that your output is indeed what I need, but with your code and having imported the right packages I still don't get the right HTML. When I added a sleep of 60 after the click method in my original code it did work, but that seems very inefficient.

Comment: @ThomasVanAssche Added the additional imports. Retest and let me know the status.

Comment: I think my IP adress just got banned from the site so I'm afraid I can't test it right now, I will let you know later. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Handle the cookies or wait for the throttling period to get over, you can retest.

Comment: Excuse me for the rookie mistakes, thats what I am I'm afraid. I didn't look at your HTML very well I think, I do get the same result as you now, but thats not what i need. The "Werkadres" (MARIA ZIEKENHUIS OOSTLAAN 11 8970  POPERINGE) is the final goal of the code. The sleep method does work if that's of any help.

Comment: @ThomasVanAssche That wasn't your requirement either, reread your question _`...how I can get the HTML code of the site AFTER running this search...`_. However, adjusting to your current requirement from the current code should be a cakewalk.

Comment: A cakewalk was a bit of an understatement in my case but i made it work! Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThomasVanAssche Glad to be able to help you.